# Is it possible to post data in queue?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've implemented instant messaging through **GCM**. At the time of sending I show dummy message until app receives acknowledgement.

In this process user can send multiple messages. all through `AsyncTask`. Sometimes messages are not sending in queue.

My question is:

Is there any method to send messages in queue?

Answer (score 0):

You can take look at these superb queuing library one from Path team and other from Sqaure team

https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue

https://github.com/square/tape

I also heard about "GCM Network Manager" last week in google i/o, check that too.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager